# ADFS 2.0 Not handling 'Extension' tag in SAML AuthnRequest - Throwing Exception MSIS7015

Tags: saml-2.0, adfs, adfs2.0

We currently have ADFS 2.0 with hotfix 2 rollup installed and working properly as an identity provider for several external relying parties using SAML authentication. This week we attempted to add a new relying party, however, when a client presents the authentication request from the new party, ADFS simply returns an error page with a reference number and does not prompt the client for credentials.

I checked the server ADFS 2.0 event log for the reference number, but it is not present (searching the correlation id column). I enabled the ADFS trace log, re-executed the authentication attempt and this message was presented:

```
Failed to process the Web request because the request is not valid. Cannot get protocol message from HTTP query. The following errors occurred when trying to parse incoming HTTP request:

Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageException: MSIS7015: This request does not contain the expected protocol message or incorrect protocol parameters were found according to the HTTP SAML protocol bindings.
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(HttpContext httpContext)
at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.FederationPassiveContext.EnsureCurrent(HttpContext context)
```

As the message indicates that the request is not well formed, I went ahead and ran the request through xmlsectool and validated it against the SAML protocol XSD (http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-schema-protocol-2.0.xsd) and it came back clean:

```
C:\Users\ebennett\Desktop\xmlsectool-1.2.0>xmlsectool.bat --validateSchema --inFile metaauth_kld_request.xml --schemaDirectory . --verbose
INFO  XmlSecTool - Reading XML document from file 'metaauth_kld_request.xml'
DEBUG XmlSecTool - Building DOM parser
DEBUG XmlSecTool - Parsing XML input stream
INFO  XmlSecTool - XML document parsed and is well-formed.
DEBUG XmlSecTool - Building W3 XML Schema from file/directory 'C:\Users\ebennett\Desktop\xmlsectool-1.2.0\.'
DEBUG XmlSecTool - Schema validating XML document
INFO  XmlSecTool - XML document is schema valid
```

So, I'm thinking that ADFS isn't playing full compliance with the SAML specification. To verify, I manually examined the submitted AuthnRequest, and discovered that our vendor is making use of the 'Extensions' element to embed their custom properties (which is valid, according to the SAML specification) (note: "ns33" below correctly namspaces "urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" elsewhere in the request)

```
  <ns33:Extensions>
    <vendor_ns:fedId xmlns:vendor_ns="urn:vendor.name.here" name="fedId" value="http://idmfederation.vendorname.org"/>
  </ns33:Extensions>
```

If I remove the previous element from the AuthnRequest and resubmit it to ADFS, everything goes swimmingly. And, in fact, I can leave the 'Extensions' container and simply edit out the vendor namespaced element, and ADFS succeeds.

Now, I guess I have 3 questions:

1. Why was the reference number not logged to the ADFS log? That really would have helped my early debugging efforts
2. Is it a known issue that ADFS's SAML handler cannot handle custom elements defined within the Extensions element, and if so, is there a way to add support (or at least not crash while handling it)? My vendor has offered to change the SAML AuthnRequest generated to omit that tag, but said that it 'may take some time'-- and we all know what that means...
3. Does anyone think that installing ADFS hotfix rollup 3 will address this situation? I didn't see anything in the doc to indicate the affirmative.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: re: #2 - ADFS is SAML 2.0 IDP Lite and SP Lite compliant. However, I would expect that ADFS is not designed to handle custom extensions regardless of version. Basically, just because a certain extension is allowed in the spec, doesn't mean that every vendor has to support it to be compliant.

Comment: ah, I wasn't previously aware of the "Lite" operational modes. thanks for the information- I think that will give me a direction to focus my investigation. And yeah, I had little hope that ADFS would do anything useful with the vendor extension- but I had expected it to not crash when given this extra information. After all, ADFS does accept the Extensions container as part of the AuthnRequest without blowing up... why not gracefully ignore the contents of the container? Thanks again for your input.

Answer (score 1):

When facing a MSIS7015 ADFS error, the best place to start would be enabling ADFS Tracing.  Login to the ADFS server as admin and run the following command.  If you have a very busy ADFS server, might be wise to do it when the server is not as busy.

```
C:\Windows\System32\> wevtutil sl “AD FS Tracing/Debug” /L:5
C:\Windows\System32\> eventvwr.msc
```

In Event Viewer select “Application and Services Logs”, right-click and select “View – Show Analytics and Debug Logs”
Go to AD FS Tracing – Debug, right-click and select “Enable Log” to start Trace Debugging.

Process your ADFS login / logout steps and when finished, go to the event viewer mmc find the sub tree AD FS Tracing – Debug, right-click and select “Disable Log” to stop Trace Debugging.

Look for EventID 49 - incoming AuthRequest - and verify values are not being sent with CAPs value.  For example, in my case, it was I was receiving the following values: IsPassive=**'False'**, ForceAuthn=**'False**'

In my case, to address the issue, all I needed to do was create incoming claim transformer rule - for the distinct endpoints.

[image: Edit Claim Rule GUI]

[image: Claim Rule Editor]

Once the CAPs were transformed to lower case true and false, authentication started working.